# Qual é a diferença entre reset e clear no Terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal

No `Terminal`, qual é a diferença entre os comandos `reset` e `clear`?

Estou utilizando o `Terminal` do `Ubuntu` e, aparentemente, os dois comandos limpam a tela.

Comment: reset aparentemente reseta todos os comandos, e clear apenas limpa as telas, no caso o reset seria a mesma coisa que reescrever todos os comandos novamente.

Comment: Isso foi uma metáfora?

Comment: Utilize o comando `man`, `man reset` e `man clear`, você vai ver exatamente o que cada comando faz e vai entender a diferença entre eles

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
clear
```

Elimina o conteúdo da área visível. O que ele na verdade faz é rolar a barra para que você veja somente a área limpa. Mas se você der um **scroll** para cima verá todo o conteúdo anterior lá.

```
reset
```

Realmente limpa o terminal. Equivale a fechar e abrir um novo terminal.